# fadeto not working jquery

Tags: jquery

My all code working fine. I implement fadeout effect of jquery in script but this function is not working `.hide()` working but not `fadeto()`. please help me. thanks you so much.

```
$(function() { 
    $( "#slider").slider({ 
       stop: function(event, ui) {
            $("#list").fadeTo("fast", 0.03);
              $.ajax({
              url: "search.php",
              cache: false,
              async: false,
             data: "",
                  success: function(html){
                $("#list").fadeTo("fast", 1);
                $("#list").html(html);

              }
            });

         }
    });
});
```

My showing simple HTML Table on click. here is my table

```
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="500px">
    <tr class="title">
        <td align="center" width="10%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Shape</td>
        <td align="center" width="11%"bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Weight</td>
        <td align="center" width="11%"bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Certificate</td>
        <td align="center" width="12%"bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Cut</td>
        <td align="center" width="10%"bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Color</td>
        <td align="center" width="10%"bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Clarity</td>
        <td align="center" width="12%"bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Price</td>
        <td align="center" width="12%"bgcolor="#CCCCCC">View Detail</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="11%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @silex firefox,chrome,ie

Comment: Ok, and what about some HTML as @Abdul Kader already suggested?

Comment: Is the HTML you pasted related to your jquery code?

Comment: @Tudorizer  Yes.I'm showing that table on ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to fade the table in/out. You don't have the id on the table set!

```html
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="500px">
```

should be

```html
<table id="list" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="500px">
```